# ActiveRecord group by multiply field and count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, group-by

I have the following:

```
Question.group('date(created_at), type').count
```

That returns:

```
# => {"5"=>4, "2"=>3, "1"=>4, "4"=>1, "3"=>1}
```

Instead of:

```
# => {["2013-12-02", "5"]=>3, ["2013-12-02", "2"]=>2, ["2013-12-02", "1"]=>2}...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Different, here it's count not sum.

Comment: Doesn't matter, `count` vs `sum` is just an irrelevant detail, the underlying problem is how AR deals with string-based GROUP BY conditions and aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to group the date and type together using square brackets.  Try this:

`Question.group(["date(created_at)", :type]).count`

Simply splitting the parameters passed to `group` will work, but I think the above makes it more clear:

`Question.group("date(created_at)", :type).count`

Both will give you results like:

`["<date>", <type>] => count`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the parameters to `group` separately as follows:

```
Question.group('date(created_at)', 'type').count
```